# AWS Create user pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk, aws-userpools

Create user pool with lambda function

User: arn:aws:sts::********:assumed-role/{my funcutin name} is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:CreateUserPool on resource: * because no identity-based policy allows the cognito-idp:CreateUserPool action

Comment: Whats the language inside of lambda function?

Comment: The solution here is to create a policy that have access to cognito (more specifically CreateUserPool action) and then assign that policy to the role that you are using with the lambda function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the IAM role the cognito-idp:CreateUserPool permission